# Recursion reverse indexing std::array

Tags: c++, recursion, stdarray

This is a simple piece of code that uses recursion:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using std::array;
using std::size_t;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#define ARRAY_SZ 3

enum class direction{forward, backward};

int circular (array<size_t,ARRAY_SZ>::iterator, array<size_t, ARRAY_SZ>::iterator, direction);

int main (void){

    array<size_t,ARRAY_SZ> A = {5,1,3};
    array<size_t,ARRAY_SZ> B = {4,2,2};

    auto result = 0;
    //direction d = direction::forward;
    size_t distance = ARRAY_SZ - 1;
    direction d = direction::backward;

    if(d == direction::forward){
       result = circular(A.begin(),B.begin(), d);
       cout << result << endl;
    }
    else{
            result = circular(A.begin() + distance, B.begin() + distance, d);
        if(result >= 0){
            cout << ARRAY_SZ - (result + 1) << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << result << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int circular (array<size_t,ARRAY_SZ>::iterator iterA, array<size_t,ARRAY_SZ>::iterator iterB, direction d){

    static auto count = -1; 
    static size_t diff = 0;

    switch(d){
        case direction::backward:
            {
                if(*iterA > *iterB){
                    diff += *iterA - *iterB;
                    ++count;
                    return circular(--iterA, --iterB, d);
                }
                else{
                        if(*iterB - *iterA <= diff){
                            diff -= *iterB - *iterA;
                            ++count;
                            return circular(--iterA, --iterB, d);
                        }
                        else{
                            return count;
                        }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            {
                if(*iterA > *iterB){
                    diff += *iterA - *iterB;
                    ++count;
                    return circular(++iterA, ++iterB, d);
                }
                else{
                        if(*iterB - *iterA <= diff){
                            diff -= *iterB - *iterA;
                            ++count;
                            return circular(++iterA, ++iterB, d);
                        }
                        else{
                            return count;
                        }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The recursive function is

```
int circular (array<size_t,ARRAY_SZ>::iterator, array<size_t, ARRAY_SZ>::iterator, direction);
```

The implemented logic inside this function works as expected for the forward indexing of both the arrays; the recursion ends as expected returning a value of `2` for `count`.

However, in the case of reverse indexing, the recursion goes one iteration beyond the expected end point, as evinced by the following `gdb` log:

```
Thread 1 "a" hit Breakpoint 1, circular (iterA=0xffffcb78, iterB=0xffffcb58, d=direction::backward) at code.cpp:49
49          switch(d){
(gdb) n
52                      if(*iterA > *iterB){
(gdb) n
53                          diff += *iterA - *iterB;
(gdb) p *iterA
$12 = 6445809520
(gdb) p *iterB
$13 = 6445644288
(gdb)
```

As shown in the log, both `iterA` and `iterB` now point to garbage values.

Why is this only observed during reverse indexing and not during forward indexing?

Comment: *Why is this only observed during reverse indexing and not during forward indexing?* -- What did your debugging efforts reveal?

Comment: When do you check that your iterators are valid?

Comment: Three calls to `circular` happen in the backward case. The first fulfills the opening `if`, so `diff` is 1 (0+(3-2)), and `return circular(--iterA, --iterB, d);` is invoked. That call eventually falls to the related `else`.  Within that, the nested `if` is taken because `if (*iterB - *iterA <= diff)` is true (2-1 <= 1), so `diff` is set back to zero and `return circular(--iterA, --iterB, d);` is taken. Finally, we're back to the first `if (*iterA > *iterB)` being true again (5 > 4),  so`return circular(--iterA, --iterB, d);` But `iterA` and `iterB` are already at start of sequence. UB.

Comment: And FYI, switching to `direction d = direction::foward;` is also broken, but it takes an extra run through the recursion before it succumbs, this time when dereferencing the `end` iterators. I.e. it's just as broken; but you're not seeing it. Look closer.

Comment: @WhozCraig Based on my gdb debugging I could find that the recursion ends in the case of forward indexing before the invalid values in both the iterators are examined; as opposed to reverse indexing the gdb log of which I had reproduced in my original question.

Comment: Well, based on MS debugger *and* debug-iterator assertions that trip when doing things like trying to decrement an iterator already at the beginning of it sequence, or dereference an iterator sitting on `end()`, whether you realize it or not, even forward is broken with those sequences and that code.